# What database table does mysqli_connect connect to?

Tags: php, mysql

I was reading a tutorial that stated that the syntax to connect to a MySQL database is as follows:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password");
```

What confuses me is the fact that you can have multiple databases, however you aren't actually providing a database name. Does this mean that it actually connects to a set of databases, or am I missing a step in which I have to somehow specify the database in which I need to connect to?

Comment: You can specify the dbname in the `mysqli_connect`. www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
Otherwise, yes you are connecting to a database server that has multiple databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth argument is the default database name <sup>([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php))</sup>, and you can change database with [`mysqli_select_db`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_select_db).

Answer (score 2):

The mysqli_connect function can actually take 4 parameters. The last one is the database name.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "db_name");
```

That is what you need.

edit: reworded my answer based on comment. Thanks @TimWolla

Comment: Actually all of the parameters are optional.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `mysqli_connect` means you are connecting to your database.

Your format can be like this:

```
mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd")
```

Answer (score 0):

It connects to the MySQL daemon, just like the mysql command line utility would. You can access every database the selected user can access:

```
[timwolla@~]mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 665
Server version: 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

You can change your database afterwards ([`select_db`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php))

```
mysql> use test;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
```

Or specify the proper one in every query you perform by prepending the tables with the correct database:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.a;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

You can even select from multiple databases at once:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.b UNION SELECT * FROM md5.hashes LIMIT 5;
+------------+----------------------------------+
| primary    | a                                |
+------------+----------------------------------+
| 1693571230 | 520b970bb67846dbc9392ca8d487d92c |
| 702707365  | 0e86d6992bc75c2f3fb679cdf321252c |
| 2133213448 | 949c4d575ff4804de7e2a17c42bce2f1 |
| 280504773  | 3662f03fa083807e8407aa662de1aa73 |
| 130287311  | 087374e9f6f64b879705c853224ab67d |
+------------+----------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch databases using:

```
mysqli_select_db()
```

For example:

```
mysqli_select_db($connection, "db_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

It connects to the MySQL service, which then returns a resource. At this point you are not connected to a specific database, but the service itself, which is stored in the variable $connection.

You can then use mysqli_select_db() to select the database that you want to query.

The last parameter is the default database that you want to connect to, which is optional.

You would save yourself an extra step by providing the last parameter.